# AWS Cloud9 editor Typescript issues

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, cloud9-ide

I'm starting to use Typescript in my projects, however the Cloud9 editor often shows errors other editors (eg VS Code) do not.

For example if I [install the boilerplate NextJS (14)](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation#automatic-installation)

```
$ npx create-next-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
create-next-app@14.1.2
Ok to proceed? (y) y
✔ What is your project named? … test-cloud9-ts
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? … No / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in /home/nathan/gitRepos/test-cloud9-ts/test-cloud9-ts.
```

then create an environment in the new folder and open it through the Cloud9 panel...

layout.tsx has issues resolving the Metadata type from next

[image: Cloud9 Typescript issue]

In the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.87.0) there are no errors

[image: VS Studio Code no Typescript errors]

Why is VS Code ostensibly *smarter*, and how can Cloud9 be "fixed"? Here's [the boilerplate Nextjs 14 repo](https://github.com/quickshiftin/test-cloud9-ts).

**EDIT (JS/TS env on dev box)**

```
$ tsc --version
Version 5.3.3

$ npm --version
10.2.4

$ node --version
v20.11.1

$ nvm --version
0.39.1
```

Comment: It may just be that C9 has limited TS support, which is sad, given it's a browser based editor lol. For now I'm using the SSH support in VS Code and have sent a support ticket to AWS letting them know they may be shedding customers.

Comment: Can you check the output of the commands mentioned in Step 1 of [TypeScript tutorial for AWS Cloud9](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-typescript.html)?

Comment: @VonC thx for scoping out this question! Versions have been added.

Comment: Web browsers don’t interpret TypeScript though, so why is it sooo surprising?

Comment: https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/create-a-package#packagejson. https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud9+package.json+location

Comment: It's surprising b/c Typescript supersedes Javascript, which is what has been used to build the browser-based editor. One would assume Typescript support would be prioritized for such an editor, def not marginalized...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cloud9 requires the package.json to be at the root of the project (in the environment folder). Otherwise it does not recognise the installed packages.

Use `git clone git@someurl .` (note the period) to clone into the current directory and not create a new directory.

create-react-app does not like the `.c9` folder in the environment, so you should create it as per usual in a sub-folder, then move all the files up.

`npx create-next-app@latest`

For example if the site is called MySite, you should run
`mv MySite/* .` from the environment directory.

Comment: Thx @gunwin I'll try this today; any docs you can share in this regard?

Comment: I typically clone the project first, then point the C9 editor at top level. EG I have a `~/gitRepos` folder with all my projects, so from that folder I would do `git clone https://github.com/quickshiftin/test-cloud9-ts` which creates `~/test-cloud9-ts`, which is what I point C9 at. For the hell of it, I ran `mv test-cloud9-ts/* .` in the example project and still the errors are there.

Comment: @quickshiftin No I did not find any documentation for this. I span up and instance and tried some things. Good candidate for a canonical question this.

Comment: thanks @gunwin - new bounty started w/ 500 pts in search of a canonical answer ;)

Comment: Correction, the folder created in the aforementioned flow is `~/gitRepos/test-cloud9-ts`.

Comment: Is this canonical enough: https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/create-a-package#packagejson

Comment: @morganney not really, are you suggesting a C9 package needs to be created for every Typescript project we have? I don't see any notes to that effect in this document.

Comment: The link to the documentation was in regards to the "package.json needing to be in the top level directory" for a C9 package. This answer seems to verify that documentation through trial and error. Have you tried moving the location of your package.json file yet?

Comment: Yes, I have tried per my prior comment last week. A Cloud9 package is not the same as a project package. The link you shared is for creating a customization to Cloud9 itself...